# Django TypeError("sync_to_async can only be applied to sync functions.")

Tags: python, django

I am trying to making my class based view as async class based views. When I add sync_to_async to my api calls inside the class based view. I get an error

> TypeError: sync_to_async can only be applied to sync functions.

I don't know and can't get how to make my class based view as async class based views.
Here is my code:

```
class PaymentSerailizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Payment
    fields = (
        "quantity"
    )

@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    view = super().as_view(**initkwargs)
    view._is_coroutine = asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine
    return view

def create(self, validated_data):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_API_KEY
    object = sync_to_async(Payment.objects.get(company=self.context["request"].company))
    sub_obj = sync_to_async(stripe.Subscription.retrieve(object.sub_id))
    product = sync_to_async(stripe.Product.retrieve(sub_obj.get("items")))
```

The error I get are on each sync_to_async calls. I am not sure why I am getting this error.